# How to open a page with Selenium WebDriver (Chrome), without waiting for it to load in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

`driver.get(URL)` function waits for the page to finish loading before returning to execution.

In Java there is a method `driver.navigate().to(URL)`, which does not wait for the page to load, however, I cannot find such method in Python.

For firefox, I could run `profile.set_preference("webdriver.load.strategy", "unstable")`, however Chrome does not have such preference.

There is also `driver.set_page_load_timeout(0.2)` with `TimeoutException` handling
However, when the exception is handled, the chrome driver stops loading the page.

**EDIT**: Rephrased the question a bit and added one solution that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"   # Do not wait for full page load
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps, executable_path="path/to/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('some url')
#some code to run straight away
```

This code will not wait for the page to fully load before it moves to the next line. When using the 'None' Page load strategy you will probably have to make your own custom wait to check if the elements or element you need are done loading.

You could use:

```
import time
time.sleep()
```

Or if you want to only wait the required time before an element has loaded in:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(
    ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "your_element_id"))
)
```

This should help you with whatever you are trying to do. Since you gave no code, I can only assume this will work as I could not give a specific answer for a specific web page.